# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) angularjs

Tags: angularjs

my config:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/ajax/create', {
        templateUrl: 'view/pagination/pagination.html',
        controller: 'AjaxCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/ajax/update/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'view/pagination/pagination.html',
        controller: 'AjaxCtrl'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/ajax/delete/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'view/pagination/pagination.html',
        controller: 'AjaxCtrl'
    });

}])
```

my code process:

```
        $scope.doEdit = function(item) {
            var notice = "Item #" + item.id + " has been edited with amount: " + item.amount;

            $http.put('/ajax/update/' + item.id).then(function(data) {
                alert(notice);
            });
        }
```

I'm trying all method put, delete
all of them have error without method get althought it still working

error in console

[image]

Answer (score 0):

a `405 Method Not Allowed` indicates that the user agent (the web browser, in most cases) has requested a valid resource using an invalid HTTP method. This could happen in a few different circumstances:

- The user agent is accidentally sending an incorrect HTTP method.
- The server is expecting only a handful of valid HTTP methods for the
  requested resource.

So look into your server which HTTP method the API supports.

Comment: i don't know why incorrect HTTP method and code still working

Comment: you can give me 
solution

Comment: Please share your server side code. EG the "/update/:id" API.

Comment: file api: [
    { "id": 1, "name": "iPhone 5s", "amount": 10 },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Nexus 5", "amount": 12 },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Xperia Z1", "amount": 13 },
    { "id": 4, "name": "Motorola X", "amount": 8 },
    { "id": 5, "name": "Galaxy S4", "amount": 21 }
]

Answer (score 0):

add this **nginx.conf**

```
    add_header Allow "GET, POST, HEAD, PUT" always;

    if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|PUT)$ ) {
        return 405;
    }
```